# How do I dismiss the webview presented by Monotouch dialog HTML element?

Tags: webview, xamarin.ios, xamarin

Monotouch Dialog makes it really easy to open up a webview:

```
var web = new HtmlElement ("myWebview", "http://yahoo.co.uk");
```

But how do I dismiss it in a clean way with a top navigation bar?

Answer (score 0):

It generates a (named) back button in the navigation bar, above the html. The back button's name will match the name of the Section you're returning to.

Comment: I am using flyout navigation controller along with a top bar.  I have a feeling the back button is hidden by the top bar.  Is there an override to force the html elements back button/top bar to come to the top most layer?